# What is the distribution of the ratio of non-standard normal square?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose that ${\bf y}\sim N_4({\mu},\sigma^2I)$, and $\sum^4_{i=1}\mu_i=0$. Find the distribution of
$$\frac{2(y_1-y_3)^2}{(\sum^4_{i=1}y_i)^2}$$

I guess there missed something in the numerator, since if it is
$$\frac{2[(y_1-y_3)-(\mu_1-\mu_3)]^2}{(\sum^4_{i=1}y_i)^2}$$
I can figure out it is $F_{1,1}$ distribution, because then the ratio is just the ratio of two independent (the independence can be done by checking the covariance) standard normal square.

Any comment? Thanks~

Comment: The mean of corresponding $y_i$.

Comment: For the problem as given: You can show that $(Y_1-Y_3)$ is independent of $(Y_1+Y_3)$ and so the numerator and denominator of $\frac{2(Y_1-Y_3)^2}{(Y_1+Y_2+Y_3+Y_4)^2}$ are independent.  With your modification I agree the numerator and denominator would be squares of _zero mean_ independent Gaussians.

Comment: You can integrate a 2-d Gaussian PDF over a ball centered at the origin, but I don't know how to integrate over a shifted ball.  So assuming $\mu_1=\mu_3$ indeed makes the problem doable.